# jquery click handles extra function after boolean changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, boolean

[In this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Solver/cXz7L/) I have a div that moves when another element is clicked and moves back when all elements except for the div itself are clicked. I check what position it is in with a boolean. the problem I have is that after the boolean changed it executes the other function without another click so the div just moves back and forth on each click.

This is the code:

```
<p>Click me!</p>
<div></div>
```

---

```
div {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
background-color: red;
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var isRight = false;
function toRight() {
    $('div').animate({'margin-left':'60%'}, 500);
    isRight = true;
}
function toLeft() {
    $('div').animate({'margin-left':'0'}, 500);
    isRight = false;
}
$('*:not(div)').on('click', function() {
    if (isRight) {
        toLeft();
    }
});
$('p').on('click', function () {
    if (!(isRight)) {
        toRight();
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are alomost close, but you will need to exclude both `div` and `p` for next click.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isRight = false;
    function toRight() {
        $('div').animate({'margin-left':'60%'}, 500);
        isRight = true;
    }
    function toLeft() {
        $('div').animate({'margin-left':'0'}, 500);
        isRight = false;
    }
    $('*:not(div,p)').on('click', function(e) {
        if (isRight && !($(e.target).is("div"))) {
            toLeft();
            e.stopPropagation();            
        }
    });
    $('p').on('click', function (e) {
        if (!(isRight)) {
            toRight();
            e.stopPropagation();            
        }
    });
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cXz7L/2/)**

Comment: Ohh sorry, updating it... see it now... @Solver Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

add a class to that div and do like this:

```
  $('*').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()

 if(!$(this).hasClass("block") && !($(this).hasClass("clickme")))
 {
    if (isRight) {
        toLeft();
    }
 }
});
$('p').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!(isRight)) {
        toRight();
    }

});
```

and on same `p` tag click if you want to move it back to right,you can handle it using `else` part:

```
$('p').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!(isRight)) {
        toRight();
    }
    else
    {
        toLeft();
    }
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/H5NvZ/1/)

[**Second Version**](http://jsfiddle.net/H5NvZ/2/)

Comment: It does solve parrt of the problem but when I click the p element again it moves 2 times and it still moves back when I click the div.

Comment: it moves two times because i added else part

Comment: It still moves 2 times when I delete the else part? And it can't move when the div is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing these:

```
$('*:not(div)').on('click', function() {
    if (isRight) {
        toLeft();
    }
});
$('p').on('click', function () {
    if (!(isRight)) {
        toRight();
    }
});
```

To these:

```
$('*:not(div)').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (isRight) {
        toLeft();
    }
});
$('p').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (!(isRight)) {
        toRight();
    }
});
```

Comment: And how is he supposed to bring box back?

Comment: He said that the both functions are executed with a single click. This might be because of event bubbling. stopPropagation stops the said bubbling.

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. It can't come back now.